# React SetState in event handler behaves differently with data mocked and data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have am reproducing exactly the same case ( same code ) between two scenarios.

1. With data mocked
2. With data requesting from an API

1) Case with Data Mocked => https://codesandbox.io/s/select-demo-0e90s works as expected

The data mocked is the following

```
const [items] = React.useState([
  { id: "1", name: "First Element" },
  { id: "2", name: "Second Element" },
  { id: "3", name: "Third Element" }
]);
```

`setSelectedName(item.name)` => *returns the item name correctly*

2) Case with API Request ( To allow the the request CORS plugin Chrome extension has to activated ) => https://codesandbox.io/s/select-demo-71u7h

The data is coming from a call request in `action/index.js` => `fetchLeaguesList()`

In the `League.js` component

`setSelectedLeagueName(item.name)`  => *TypeError Cannot read property 'name' of undefined, `item` in this case is undefined*

So my question is why `item` is undefined in my second case? How can i fix it in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because inside `League.js` on line 19 you do
`const item = items.find(item => item.id === value);`

But the JSON model that comes back from the API is not formed with the `id` property, but rather `league_id`.

You should then change the line to 
`const item = items.find(item => item.league_id == value);`

Comment: Correct and also == and not ===